# Deleting a pointer to global variable?

Tags: c++, pointers, global-variables

So, I have two global variables, that I want to point to object of a certain class.
I have them declared in one .h file as

```
extern Obj* pointer.
```

I initialize that variable inside my main function, as follows:

```
pointer = new Obj();
```

Later on, I call some functions inside main etc.
Can I call delete operator at the end of main, like so:

```
delete pointer;
```

My main, in general would look like:

```
int main(){
    pointer = new Obj();
    //...
    delete pointer;
}
```

Comment: Use unique_ptr and it will automatically deleted at the end of day.

Comment: Or just `int main() { Obj stackObj; pointer = &stackObj; /****/ }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is syntactically valid. 
However, it would be a bad practice to allocate/deallocate global pointers in this way, as these are likely to be shared elsewhere and result in difficult to track bug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since it is allocated in `main()`, deleting it in the end of `main()` is good.

Comment: And what if i define it, before main, like `extern Obj* ptr = NULL`
and then allocate it after in main, and delete it in main?

Comment: @Nicolas: That's still allocated in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

So here's an easier way, that cannot leak:

```
int main()
{
    Obj o;
    pointer = &o;

    // ...


    // automatically freed at the end of the scope
    // you may also want to do
    // pointer = nullptr;
    // so cleanup code knows the object is already dead
}
```

Comment: So, if i understand correctly, if `pointer` is for example a global variable, i can create a new object inside main, and then assign the pointer the address of the object?

This way, destructor of obj will be automatically called at the end of the scope?

Comment: @Nicholas: Yes, absolutely.  The object will survive as long as `main` is running... which is the entire length of the program except for global constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your global variable might be used at multiple places, `shared_ptr` would be a better approach.

But for that you will have to check for the last resource accessing it and deallocating it.

Also, you may consider `unique_ptr` if you think that you will be using it at a single place